# System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 47 of the input. The input has )

Tags: sql, geoserver

I have a table in  sqlserverdb which contains column name EntityType, EntityJson.In EntityJson column contains following json value,

```
{"EntityId":{"Type":"String","Value":"bf58bbc6-0a5a-b9e0-4fb6-5e55604a1b68"},"Name":{"Type":"string","Value":"GasAssets"},"TenantName":{"Type":"string","Value":"v2rdemo"},"TenantId":{"Type":"string","Value":"c091e548-b45a-49b4-b8ec-2cb5e27c7af6"},"EntityType":{"Type":"string","Value":"EntityAssets"},"CreatedBy":{"Type":"string","Value":""},"ModifiedBy":{"Type":"string","Value":""},"Created":{"Type":"string","Value":""},"Modified":{"Type":"string","Value":""},"Parent":{"Type":"string","Value":""},"LastChat":{"Type":"string","Value":""},"Latitude":{"Type":"string","Value":-33.3479019999504},"Longitude":{"Type":"string","Value":6.203906305532271}}
```

and EntityType column value is "EntityAssets".

On GeoServer I have written the following query

```
SELECT
  geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST(JSON_VALUE(EntityJson, '$.Latitude.Value') As CHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(JSON_VALUE(EntityJson, '$.Longitude.Value') AS CHAR(20)) + ')', 4326) as geometria 
FROM
   dbo.Entities 
where
   EntityType = 'EntityAssets'
```

While previewing layer on click openlayer I'm getting same exception.

But Inside Microsoft Sql Server Mgmt Studio  running it's working fine with where clause and if i remove where clause and Execute again Query without where clause getting same Exception on Sql Server Mgmt studio.

> A number is expected at position 47 of the input. The input has ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without seeing your data, but the error sounds like you have a row with no or empty `Latitude.Value` and `Longitude.Value`. You will get a very similar error by running this query:

```
SELECT
  geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + '' + ' ' + '' + ')', 4326) as geometria 
FROM
   dbo.Entities
```

This simulates your two CASTs returning empty strings.

See also [this old question on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ada66f3b-3edf-49c3-8748-3148a76d89bc/net-framework-error-occurred-during-execution-of-userdefined-routine-or-aggregate-geography?forum=transactsql).

Comment: Thanks @kthy .Yes if empty it's give error.could you tell me there is way to skip blank row means in column json Latitude and Longitude is not present by sql query before where clause while selecting query.